# Can I move my GTA 5 account from my Xbox 360 to my PS4?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Can I move my Xbox 360 account to my PS4?

Comment: Are you asking if you can move your Gamer Profile from one console to the other, a save game, or something else?

Comment: @TZHX  Not a dupe.  That question was a same gen game transfer.  Cross gen game transfer is another matter.

Comment: @CaulynDarr The base question in both is "Can I move my game progress between platforms".

Comment: @TZHX The linked question is very specific for ps3 to xbox 360.  This question is for 360 to ps4.  They may seem similar, but are very different because there actually is a path to transfer the data across the generations but not between platforms of the same generation.  The other question also doesn't provide an actual helpful answer to this particular question while still answering the specific question posed there.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question. As per my research, and understanding from other games, you CAN transfer from 360 to PS4. You CANNOT transfer from 360 to ps3 (the linked question). If they are exact duplicates, they would not have alternate answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean your GTA online character profiles, yes you can.  I took mine from 360 to PS4.

[Please check out this link with exact instructions for doing so.](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-or-Xbox-One)

The short version is you link your PSN account to your Rockstar Social Club profile along with your old XBox live profile.  Then when you log into GTA online for the first time you'll get prompted with the option to start the transfer.  I believe you only get one shot at it.

Single player game progress was not transferred.